# Create instance of List using reflection c#

Tags: c#, list, reflection, instance

I work on method which will dynamically creates instances of collections in our entities. My problem is when I create new record which has to be inserted into database, my `ICollection` navigation properties are always null and in my safe method

I have to use something like this below to create new `List` and its definitely not good approach. If I dont create instance of `List`, `Mapper` will throw error that it cannot map `Collection` of something to `null`, for example it cannot map List of `Categories` to null.

Sample of my safe method

```
//check if record exists in database so i know if have to update or insert record (based on entity Id)
var entity = repository.GetById(detail.Id)
//....some code removed for brevity
if (entity.Categories == null)
{
    entity.Categories = new List<Category>();
}
if (entity.UserContacts == null)
{
    entity.UserContacts = new List<UserContact>();
}
//dto => entity
Mapper.PopulateEntity(dto, entity);
//update or insert later on.
```

Extension method which has to create instance of `List<T>` for example `new List<Category>()` like its shown above.

```
public TEntity InitializeEntity(TEntity entity)
    {
        var properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            if (typeof(ICollection<TEntity>).Name == (prop.PropertyType.Name))
            {   
                var get = prop.GetGetMethod();
                //get assembly with entity namespace and class name
                var fullName = get.GetBaseDefinition().ReturnType.GenericTypeArguments[0].AssemblyQualifiedName;

                //create instance of object
                var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(fullName));

                //check if property is null or if get some value, dont want to rewrite values from database
                var value = prop.GetValue(entity);
                if (value == null)
                {
                    var listType = typeof(List<>);
                    var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(myObj.GetType());
                    Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType);
                }
            }
        }
        return entity;
    }
```

For some reason its not creating any instances at all and I cannot figure out where is problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set value to property via `prop.SetValue`. Here is a bit cleaned up version of your code with that problem fixed:

```
public static TEntity InitializeEntity<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
{
    var properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        if (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>))
        {                                        
            //check if property is null or if get some value, dont want to rewrite values from database
            var value = prop.GetValue(entity);
            if (value == null) {
                var itemType = prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                var listType = typeof(List<>);
                var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(itemType);
                prop.SetValue(entity, Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType));
            }
        }
    }
    return entity;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah its much cleaner version and works perfectly. Thanks